# Compiling CyanogenMod for lg g2 d802

Tags: android, building, cyanogenmod, rom

I'm trying to build CyanogenMod for intl G2 (the only change I've made is to add halo)

for the repo init I've done:

```
repo init -u git://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git -b cm-11.0 -g all,-notdefault,d802,lge
```

And then repo sync -j8

After that, like I've said, I've added halo.

And now I'm trying to build by doing:

```
$ source build/envsetup.sh
$ breakfast d802
```

but the only things I get is:

```
root@synnyg-PC:~/CM/G2# breakfast d802
including vendor/cm/vendorsetup.sh
build/core/product_config.mk:238: *** _nic.PRODUCTS.[[device/lge/d802/cm.mk]]: "device/lge/g2-common/g2.mk" does not exist. Arrêt.
Device d802 not found. Attempting to retrieve device repository from CyanogenMod Github (http://github.com/CyanogenMod).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build/tools/roomservice.py", line 76, in <module>
    result = json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen(githubreq).read().decode())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
build/core/product_config.mk:238: *** _nic.PRODUCTS.[[device/lge/d802/cm.mk]]: "device/lge/g2-common/g2.mk" does not exist. Arrêt.

** Don't have a product spec for: 'cm_d802'
** Do you have the right repo manifest?
```

I don't understand because when I take a look to device, there is no lge/d802 directory. By doing the init command, I would have to download specific files...

also lunch and breakfast command gave me the same error...

Do you have an idea where I'm wrong and what can I do ? I think I've to download the device specific files but how can I do this (if this is the error) ? I don't see...
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Generally speaking, you don't need to add the `-g` flag to the `init` command at all.  Take a look at the full instructions for building cyanogenmod for your device [here](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Build_for_d802).  The device source tree you are looking for is located [here](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_device_lge_d802), and should be pulled in automatically when you do the `breakfast` command.